# Format minutes into hours and minutes as a decimal number in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

Is there a clean and simple method of formatting an integer which is a count of a whole number of minutes into a decimal representation of hours and minutes. It's a great shame that there is not such thing as a Timespan in T-SQL to support this.

Just to be clear what I mean by this is if I have 70 minutes, I want to covert it into a representation of 1 hour and 10 minutes i.e. `1.10`. I'll also want to keep it as a varchar or something to ensure that the trailing zero is kept in place.

Is there anyway that this could be created as a custom function in SQL so that it can be resused from different queries?

Comment: after lots of searching i found awesome answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733616/how-to-convert-number-of-minutes-to-hhmm-format-in-tsql)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get the hours, you want to divide by 60. To get the remaining minutes, you want to either take the total minutes mod 60 or the difference between the total minutes and hours times 60. To make the remainder appear to the right of the decimal place, divide by 100.0:

```
SELECT minutes / 60 + (minutes % 60) / 100.0 ...
```

Note that you'll lose the trailing zero and IMHO storing a time duration this way is a bad idea because a)you can't do any more math with it and b)someone's going to get confused when they look at this code later.

You're much better off to use a string representation like the following (and I recommend the use of ':' instead of '.' again, to signify *this is not a number*):

```
SELECT CAST((minutes / 60) AS VARCHAR(8)) + ':' + 
       RIGHT('0' + CAST((minutes % 60) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) ...
```

---

As far as creating a custom function, you can make a stored procedure and then call it from other code. Note that the stored procedure will have to be created in each database.

<strike>Not sure making the stored procedure is worth the effort though, unless you want to be fancier and return a TimeSpan-like row.</strike>

Comment: Just remember that if you are going to divide an integer and hope to get decimals back, you should put the result into the appropriate data type.

Comment: I don't think you get what i mean. If i have 70 minutes, i want to covert it into a representation of 1hour and 10 minutes i.e. 1:10. 

I'll reword my question to make this clear

Comment: -1 I'm afraid this is not what he's looking for. idstam has the right answer.

Comment: @daffers: You're right, I didn't understand the first time around. Like I said, I must have been missing something.

Comment: @jmgant: Yeah, I fixed my answer now that I understand what the question was looking for. Check the revision of the OP when I first posted this answer and tell me you don't read it the same way tho... :)

Comment: @lc. I'm implementing your string representation (second part) it runs into trouble if there is less than 10 minutes from the modulus. e.g. 66 minutes becomes 1:6 instead of 1:06...

Comment: @Geronimo You're right it wasn't a perfect representation. I've edited my answer which should hopefully fix the issue.

Comment: Works for me. +1 for you!

Answer (score 1):

```
select 70/60 + ( 70 % 60)/100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a while trying to do the same thing, heres how i done it:

```
convert( varchar, cast((RouteMileage / @average_speed) as integer))+ ':' +  convert( varchar, cast((((RouteMileage / @average_speed) - cast((RouteMileage / @average_speed) as integer)) * 60) as integer)) As TravelTime,

dateadd( n, -60 * CAST( (RouteMileage / @average_speed) AS DECIMAL(7,2)), @entry_date) As DepartureTime
```

OUTPUT:

```
DeliveryDate                TravelTime             DepartureTime
2012-06-02 12:00:00.000       25:49         2012-06-01 10:11:00.000
```

Comment: You're adding the same answer to multiple, different questions? Copy&paste error or something? And please consider, if you don't add something new to others answers, you don't have to revive a 3 year old post. Thanks for your effort, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
CAST(Duration/60 + (duration % 60) /100.0 as Decimal(10,1))
```

Answer (score -2):

In SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT format(DATEADD(minute, 70, 0), N'hh\.mm')
```