# How to convert number of minutes to hh:mm format in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, type-conversion, datediff

I have a select query that has **`DURATION`** column to calculate number of Minutes . I want to convert those minutes to `hh:mm` format.

Duration has values like `60, 120,150`

**For example:**

**60** becomes     **01:00** hours

**120** becomes    **02:00** hours

**150** becomes  **02:30** hours

Also, this is how I retrieve **DURATION** (`Minutes`)

```
DATEDIFF(minute, FirstDate,LastDate) as 'Duration (Minutes)'
```

Comment: Will there ever be a situation where the duration exceeds a 24 hour period?

Comment: i got the awesome answer for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733616/how-to-convert-number-of-minutes-to-hhmm-format-in-tsql)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can convert the duration to a date and then format it:

```
DECLARE
    @FirstDate datetime,
    @LastDate datetime

SELECT
    @FirstDate = '2000-01-01 09:00:00',
    @LastDate = '2000-01-01 11:30:00'

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(12), 
       DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, @FirstDate, @LastDate), 0), 114) 

/* Results: 02:30:00:000 */
```

For less precision, modify the size of the varchar:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5), 
       DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, @FirstDate, @LastDate), 0), 114) 

/* Results: 02:30 */
```

Comment: Awesome, less precision option worked perfectly well. First and Last dates are already date-time formatted. So I just needed last 2 lines.

Comment: This is great and was helpful for solving my issue too, but just a word of warning, it doesn't handle negative differences.  
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEADD(minute, -90, 0), 114)
I have -90 and it gives me 22:30, rather than "-1:30"

Comment: I also had the issue with negative times.  The solution here resolves it: [Answer titled "Lean and simple conversion"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157844/how-do-i-convert-negative-seconds-to-hhmmss)   `CASE WHEN RPAYCODE.TIMEINSECONDS < 0 THEN '-' ELSE '' END  -- sign
+ CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(s, ABS(RPAYCODE.TIMEINSECONDS), 0), 108) -- hh:mm:ss`  @Ads

Comment: Careful, If you want accurate high precision(like 12) you need to change the "DateDiff" to "millisecond"(or the appropriate [diff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql)), as the inner function returns a int.

Comment: This does not handle counting beyond `23:59`.  If you had a calculation that produced something like `102:00` Hours, then this would erroneously contextualize `06:00` Hours.

Answer (score 24):

This function is to convert duration in minutes to readable hours and minutes format. i.e 2h30m. It eliminates the hours if the duration is less than one hour, and shows only the hours if the duration in hours with no extra minutes.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MinutesToDuration]
(
    @minutes int 
)
RETURNS nvarchar(30)

AS
BEGIN
declare @hours  nvarchar(20)

SET @hours = 
    CASE WHEN @minutes >= 60 THEN
        (SELECT CAST((@minutes / 60) AS VARCHAR(2)) + 'h' +  
                CASE WHEN (@minutes % 60) > 0 THEN
                    CAST((@minutes % 60) AS VARCHAR(2)) + 'm'
                ELSE
                    ''
                END)
    ELSE 
        CAST((@minutes % 60) AS VARCHAR(2)) + 'm'
    END

return @hours
END
```

To use this function :

```
SELECT dbo.MinutesToDuration(23)
```

Results: **23m**

```
SELECT dbo.MinutesToDuration(120)
```

Results: **2h**

```
SELECT dbo.MinutesToDuration(147)
```

Results: **2h27m**

Hope this helps!

Comment: how do you do days? Included

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure these are the best options but they'll definitely get the job done:

```
declare @durations table
(
    Duration int
)

Insert into @durations(Duration)
values(60),(80),(90),(150),(180),(1000)

--Option 1 - Manually concatenate the values together
select right('0' + convert(varchar,Duration / 60),2) + ':' + right('0' + convert(varchar,Duration % 60),2)
from @Durations

--Option 2 - Make use of the time variable available since SQL Server 2008
select left(convert(time,DATEADD(minute,Duration,0)),5)
from @durations

GO
```

Answer (score 9):

For those who need convert minutes to time with more than 24h format:

```
DECLARE @minutes int = 7830
SELECT CAST(@minutes / 60 AS VARCHAR(8)) + ':' + FORMAT(@minutes % 60, 'D2') AS [Time]
```

Result:

```
130:30
```

Answer (score 8):

```
DECLARE @Duration int

SET @Duration= 12540 /* for example big hour amount in minutes -> 209h */

SELECT CAST( CAST((@Duration) AS int) / 60 AS varchar) + ':'  + right('0' + CAST(CAST((@Duration) AS int) % 60 AS varchar(2)),2)

/* you will get hours and minutes divided by : */
```

Comment: Leading zero for the hour part: `right('0' + CAST( CAST((@Duration) AS int) / 60 AS varchar),2) + ':'  + right('0' + CAST(CAST((@Duration) AS int) % 60 AS varchar(2)),2)`

Comment: Handle negative values as well: `Select Case When @Duration<0 And @Duration>-60 Then '-' else '' End + CAST(@Duration/60 as varchar) + ':' + right('0' + CAST(Abs(@Duration) % 60 as varchar(2)),2)`

Comment: If your `@Duration` uses Precision, then you should Cast as `Decimal(10,0)` _BEFORE_ casting as `Int`.  Doing so will round your numbers up and down.  Otherwise values like `58.9` will Truncate to `0:58` (instead of `0:59`) and `59.9` will Truncate to `0:59` (instead of `1:00`).  It all depends on your needs.  I work with a 3rd Party application that doesn't handle math very well, so I'm often left with results like `4.9999999500000` that I would prefer to round.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work for me:

`SELECT FORMAT(@mins / 60 * 100 + @mins % 60, '#:0#')`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to A Ghazal, just what I needed.  Here's a slightly cleaned up version of his(her) answer:

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[fnMinutesToDuration]
(
    @minutes int 
)
RETURNS nvarchar(30)

-- Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733616/how-to-convert-number-of-minutes-to-hhmm-format-in-tsql

AS

BEGIN

return rtrim(isnull(cast(nullif((@minutes / 60)
                                , 0
                               ) as varchar
                        ) + 'h '
                    ,''
                   )
            + isnull(CAST(nullif((@minutes % 60)
                                 ,0
                                ) AS VARCHAR(2)
                         ) + 'm'
                     ,''
                    )
            )

end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select convert(varchar(5),dateadd(mi,DATEDIFF(minute, FirstDate,LastDate),'00:00'),114)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is interested in getting results as 
60 becomes 01:00 hours, 120 becomes 02:00 hours, 150 becomes 02:30 hours, this function might help:

```
    create FUNCTION [dbo].[MinutesToHHMM]
(
    @minutes int 
)
RETURNS varchar(30)
AS

BEGIN
declare @h int
        set @h= @minutes / 60
        declare @mins varchar(2)
        set @mins= iif(@minutes%60<10,concat('0',cast((@minutes % 60) as varchar(2))),cast((@minutes % 60) as varchar(2)))
return iif(@h <10, concat('0', cast(@h as varchar(5)),':',@mins)
        ,concat(cast(@h as varchar(5)),':',@mins))

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following (copy-paste the whole stuff below into immediate window / query window and execute)

```
DECLARE @foo int
DECLARE @unclefoo smalldatetime
SET @foo = DATEDIFF(minute, CAST('2013.01.01 00:00:00' AS datetime),CAST('2013.01.01 00:03:59' AS datetime)) -- AS 'Duration (Minutes)'

SET @unclefoo = DATEADD(minute, @foo, '2000.01.01')

SELECT CAST(@unclefoo AS time)
```

`@foo` stores the value you generate in your question. The "trick" comes by then:
we create a `smalldatetime` variable (in my case it's `yyyy.mm.dd` format) and increment it with your `int` value, then display (or store if you want) the `time` part only.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare function dbo.minutes2hours (
    @minutes int
)
RETURNS varchar(10)
as
begin
    return format(dateadd(minute,@minutes,'00:00:00'), N'HH\:mm','FR-fr')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How to get the First and Last Record time different in sql server....

....

```
Select EmployeeId,EmployeeName,AttendenceDate,MIN(Intime) as Intime ,MAX(OutTime) as OutTime,
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(Intime), MAX(OutTime)) as TotalWorkingHours
FROM ViewAttendenceReport WHERE AttendenceDate >='1/20/2020 12:00:00 AM' AND AttendenceDate <='1/20/2020 23:59:59 PM' 
GROUP BY EmployeeId,EmployeeName,AttendenceDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a notation of XX days YY hours and ZZ min, just try:

```
SELECT
    CAST(f.TimeAmount / 1440 AS VARCHAR(8)) + 'd ' +
    CAST((f.TimeAmount % 1440) / 60 AS VARCHAR(8)) + 'h ' +
    FORMAT(f.TimeAmount % 60, 'D2') + 'min' AS [TIME_TEXT]
FROM
    MyTable f
```