# How do I convert negative seconds to HH:MM:SS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to convert a field with positive and negative seconds to `HH:MM:SS` but failing in the process.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), RPAYCODE.TIMEINSECONDS/3600) +
':' + 
RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (RPAYCODE.TIMEINSECONDS % 3600) / 60), 2)   
AS "Pay Code Hrs"
```

When the seconds are positive it works fine `= 00:30:00`

When the seconds are negative I get this `= 0:0*`

Comment: One more question: What values are there in `TIMEINSECONDS`? When I try your SQL with values like `100` or `-30` I get rubbish ...

Comment: And one more question: Is there a ReferenceDate in your data? Some point in time from where the Seconds are running? What if your seconds are more than 24 hours...

Comment: I would like to see it as -00:30:00 and the field just stores it as a value and is never greater than 24hours

Answer (score 2):

This should handle the negative values:

```
CASE
    WHEN @time_in_seconds < 0 THEN '-'
    ELSE ''
END +
CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), ABS(RPAYCODE.TIMEINSECONDS)/3600) + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (ABS(RPAYCODE.TIMEINSECONDS) % 3600)/60), 2) AS [Pay Code Hrs]
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Lean and simple conversion

Skip all those unnecessary calculations and string operations:

```sql
CASE WHEN RPAYCODE.TIMEINSECONDS < 0 THEN '-' ELSE '' END  -- sign
+ CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(s, ABS(RPAYCODE.TIMEINSECONDS), 0), 108) -- hh:mm:ss
```

Number format **108** is `hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: This is the best answer I've seen.  It's simple and handles negative times.

Comment: I like this answer