# SSRS rounding up issue calculation

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

When I am running my SSRS report I am getting 468:30 but according to
my SP calculation should be 2550*11/60=467.5 and 5 should be changed
to 30 sec.

This is my function:

```
 Public Function FormatHHMM(ByVal Minutes As Integer) As String
    Dim iHH as Integer
    Dim iMM as Integer
    iHH = Minutes / 60
    iMM = Minutes mod 60

   Return Format(ihh,"###,##0")+":"+Format(iMM,"00")
End Function
```

This is the expression used in the field:

```
=code.FormatHHMM(Fields!Completion_BenchMarkTime.Value)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert number of minutes to hh:mm format in TSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733616/how-to-convert-number-of-minutes-to-hhmm-format-in-tsql)

Comment: Try changing `Minutes / 60` to `Minutes \ 60`. This will do integer division and effectively truncate all decimal places for the `iHH` calculation. The format expression the way that it is currently written will round to the nearest one's place.

Answer (score 1):

Use the FLOOR function in your code to "cut" the rest of the calculation.

```
iHH = floor(Minutes / 60)
```

[comparing CELLING and FLOOR](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190927%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: The OP does not want to "cut" the rest of the calculation.

Comment: As I understood the rest of the calculation is in iMM variable so you have to cut it from iHH var.