# Convert minutes in Numeric format to Hours and minutes format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I Have Minutes as 1064 in a column called 'Efforts_in_minutes' and I need the Output in the format of HH:MM (i.e) 17:44. I have tried the below Query

```
SELECT Cast(Round(Total_Effort_in_Minutes / 60, 0, 2) AS VARCHAR) 
        + ':' 
        + Cast(Total_Effort_in_Minutes % 60 AS VARCHAR(2))
FROM   PPS
```

I got the output as 17.000000:44 but What i Need is 17:44

Please advice how to achieve that.

Answer (score 3):

The use of the `Round` function is unnecessary. Just do integer division:

```
select CAST(CAST(Total_Effort_in_Minutes AS INT) / 60 AS VARCHAR)
    + ':' + CAST(Total_Effort_in_Minutes  % 60 AS VARCHAR(2) )
```

If your column *Total_Effort_in_Minutes* already has an integer data type, then you can simplify to:

```
select CAST(Total_Effort_in_Minutes / 60 AS VARCHAR)
    + ':' + CAST(Total_Effort_in_Minutes  % 60 AS VARCHAR(2) )
```

If you need the minute part to be left-padded with zero to get at least 2 digits, then:

```
select RIGHT('0' + CAST(CAST(Total_Effort_in_Minutes AS INT) / 60 AS VARCHAR), 2)
    + ':' + CAST(Total_Effort_in_Minutes  % 60 AS VARCHAR(2) )
```

Comment: It will always be truncated as they are passing a non zero value for the third parameter (`Round(999.99, 0, 2) ` = `999`) but this is easier anyway.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that, @MartinSmith. I updated the statement about using Round accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)  Now I came to a clear picture - @trincot

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATEADD(MI,Total_Effort_in_Minutes,TIMEFROMPARTS(0,0,0,0,0))
FROM   PPS
```

Best practice: The client should decide how to represent the time based on the locale, to allow for variants such as 24H clock vs AM/PM.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19887500/6298495

Creating an inline function is a good solution provided in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(5), DATEADD(mi, 1064, 0), 8)
```