# Converting INT minutes to HOUR in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I'm writing a view to get hours of holiday count from the minutes.

**Minutes data type is INT in the data table**

I wrote this but it doesn't work:

```
DATEPART(HOUR, CONVERT(DATETIME, '00:' + CAST(S.availablevacations AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ':00:000', 114))
```

> COMPILER ERROR: Create View failed because no column name was
>   specified for column 6.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733616/how-to-convert-number-of-minutes-to-hhmm-format-in-tsql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 2), `TotalMinutes`/ 60 + (`TotalMinutes`% 60) / 100.0)
```

this will convert you minutes to HH.MM format sql format

Comment: Different and clever approach.