# Convert minutes into hour and decimal in SQL

Tags: sql

I have been referring this solution [Format minutes into hours and minutes as a decimal number in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898658/format-minutes-into-hours-and-minutes-as-a-decimal-number-in-t-sql)

but what I want is the value after decimal should represent the correct fraction?

On converting 30 minutes to hours, this formula is incorrect

select 30/60+(30%60)/100.0 --0.30

where as the result should be:

select 30*0.0166667

Comment: Can you provide more examples of the results you want?  That is not clear to me.  What do you want for 30 mintes, 0.5 or 0.30 or something else?

Comment: 0.5 and not 0.30 and this works CAST(Minutes_logged/60.0 as decimal(10,2))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to just divide minutes by 60.0 . you can use below query.

```
SELECT 30/60.0
```

Comment: Just so it's understood, dividing by 60.0 will return a decimal (desired), whereas dividing by 30 will not (assuming this is what OP was doing).

Comment: It should be clarified that you need to divide by 60.0 not 60